# How to iterate over a collection Future in scala and modify an existing record/variable?

Tags: scala, future

This is a simplified example of what I am trying to achieve. I basically have a string that I need to modify based on the elements in a Future list of strings. Below is a short example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.matching.Regex

object FutureEx01 extends App
{

  var myString = "what the fcuk is happening here"
  val myList: Future[List[String]] = Future { List("fcuk", "shit", "motherfcuker", "ahole") }

  // TODO: iterate over myList, look at the elements and if there is a match with any word in myString, replace it.

/**

//this is what I could think of!  

  myList.map({

    listEle: String =>
      val listEleRegex: Regex = listEle.r
      myString = listEleRegex.replaceAllIn(myString,"CENSORED")
  })
*/
}
```

So I want to replace all the undesirable words in my string. Could you help me out on how to go about?

Thanks

Comment: downvoters please care to explain the downvote. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is all you need.

```
val goodString = myList.map{ bads =>
                   myString.replaceAll(bads.mkString("|"), "CENSORED")
                 }
```

The result is type `Future[String]` which will be completed when `myList` completes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use mutable state (`foldLeft` is what you want).
2. I am not sure why your `myList` thingy is a `Future`, but assuming, that's what you actually want, you need a `foldLeft` inside a `map`:

   ```
   val futureResult: Future[String] = myList.map { exclude => 
     exclude
       .foldLeft(myString) { case(str, ex) => ex.r.replaceAllIn(str, "CENSORED") }
   }
   ```

Now you can do things like `val result = Await.result(futureResult)` or
`futureResult.onComplete(println)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to split your string into an array:

```
val splitted = myString.split(" ")
```

Then you can map future:

```
val future = myList.map(splitted.diff(_))
```

This will return the future with a result. To extract the final result, you need to either await for value:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

Await.result(future, 1 second) //blocking
```

or use callback:

```
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

future.onComplete { //not blocking
    case Success(value) => println(value)
    case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace
}
```